# Variable Coefficients non homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x),$$

where $f(x)$ is some function of $x$.

Can anyone help me solve the above ODE? I wanted to use the Fourier Transform method but that variable coefficient is a problem.

My beginning of an attempt to find a solution is as follows: take $f(x)=\delta(x)$, so I can try to find the Green Function, then multiply by $x$ because the $1/x$ is a real problem, so I get
$$x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}=x\delta(x).$$

Now I take the Fourier transform of the above equation but finding a nice expression for the FT of that second order derivative term is proving to be quite difficult... Any hints?

Thank you

Comment: @Glen and @ muzzlator, thank you very much for the answers and for reminding me of my stupidity =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use fourier transforms:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} (x \cdot y'(x)) = x f(x)$$

$$ x y'(x) = \int x f(x) dx + C$$

Solve for $y'(x)$ and integrate.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$
x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{dy}{dx}\right)
$$